# Fixing line breaks in cartoDB infowindow?

Tags: carto, sql

I am having trouble with my cartoDB infowindow, the text breaks no matter if I resize the window. Please, take a look at the screen shot below. How can I resolve the issue? Where should I work, dataset or carto map editor?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior should have recently been fixed, but you can also implement the fix with the following:

Find this bit of code in your pop up HTML:

```
<h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title">
```

And alter it to include this:

```
<h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title" style="word-wrap: break-word">
```

Do this for every h4 class.

Comment: It's a good idea to take a look (I mean inspect) at the CSS classes available on other existing elements so you can learn how to change easily some styles to make them closer to the rest of the UI styles.